# Estou carregando essa Música corretamente com a Bass.dll?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3, ogg, bass

Com base na documentação da *Bass*, eu estou tentando carregar um arquivo ogg comum, com o seguinte código:

```pascal
var
  FFile : string;
  Music: HSAMPLE; 
  ch: HCHANNEL;
  OpenDialog1 : TOpenDialog;
begin
  Dynamic_Bass.Load_BASSDLL('Library/Bass.dll');
  Dynamic_Bass.BASS_Init(1,44000,Bass_DEVICE_SPEAKERS,0,nil);  
  OpenDialog1 := TOpenDialog.Create(nil);
  if not OpenDialog1.Execute then
    Exit;
  ffile := OpenDialog1.FileName;
  Music := BASS_SampleLoad(FALSE, PChar(ffile), 0, 0, 3, BASS_SAMPLE_OVER_POS);
  ch := BASS_SampleGetChannel(Music, False);
  BASS_ChannelSetAttribute(ch, BASS_ATTRIB_PAN, 0);
  BASS_ChannelSetAttribute(ch, BASS_ATTRIB_VOL, 1);
  BASS_ChannelPlay(ch, False);
  ShowMessage(IntToStr(BASS_ErrorGetCode));
end;
```

Ele mostra o número 5 que de acordo com a documentação, é um erro no *handle*, neste caso, na minha variável `music`. Se eu comentar essas linhas abaixo de `BASS_SampleLoad`, o código muda para 2, que significa que o arquivo não pode ser carregado. Esse é arquivo comum e não está corrompido, então minha pergunta: estou fazendo algo errado?

Comment: Acho que faltou só um link para o que é a BASS ou para sua documentação. Pelo menos para quem não conhece, ficaria difícil ajudar.

Comment: @EMBarbosa: É por isso que eu adicionei o link na minha resposta

Comment: @whosrdaddy Eu percebi. Só achei que deveria estar na pergunta ao invés de estar na resposta. De qualquer forma, bom trabalho na detecção do problema.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eu não falo português nativamente, eu usei Google Tradutor para criar a minha resposta.

[Pergunta Inglês Original](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21919289/800214)

Seu código parece estar correto, apenas certifique-se de verificar se há erros em cada chamada.

Código corrigido:

```
var
  ffile : string;
  music: HSAMPLE; 
  ch: HCHANNEL;
  opendialog1 : topendialog;

begin 
 if not Dynamic_Bass.Load_BASSDLL('Library/Bass.dll') then
  Exit;
 // change device to -1 which is the default device
 if Dynamic_Bass.BASS_Init(-1,44000,Bass_DEVICE_SPEAKERS,0,nil) then
  begin
   opendialog1 := topendialog.Create(nil);
   try
    if OpenDialog1.Execute then
     begin
      ffile := OpenDialog1.FileName;
      music := BASS_SampleLoad(FALSE, PChar(ffile), 0, 0, 3, BASS_SAMPLE_OVER_POS);
      if music <> 0 then
       begin
        ch := BASS_SampleGetChannel(music, False);
        if ch <> 0 then
         begin
          // omitted, see if the basics work   
          // BASS_ChannelSetAttribute(ch, BASS_ATTRIB_PAN, 0);
          // BASS_ChannelSetAttribute(ch, BASS_ATTRIB_VOL, 1);
          if not BASS_ChannelPlay(ch, False) then
           ShowMessage(inttostr(bass_errorgetcode));
         end
        else
         ShowMessage(inttostr(bass_errorgetcode));
       end
      else
       ShowMessage(inttostr(bass_errorgetcode));
     end;
   finally  
    OpenDialog1.Free;
   end;
  end
 else
  ShowMessage(inttostr(bass_errorgetcode));
end;
```

**ATUALIZAÇÃO**

Eu deveria ter visto isso antes, o seu código de falha porque `BASS_SampleLoad` espera que o nome do arquivo esteja no formato ANSI, [a documentação menciona claramente isto](http://www.un4seen.com/doc/#bass/BASS_SampleLoad.html), uma vez que você usa Delphi XE3 e as Strings são Unicode, você deve fornecer o flag `BASS_UNICODE` para indicar isso.

Assim, a linha `Bass_SampleLoad` torna-se:

```
music := BASS_SampleLoad(FALSE, PChar(ffile), 0, 0, 3, BASS_SAMPLE_OVER_POS 
          or BASS_UNICODE);
```

Comment: Eu não tenho muito conhecimento sobre os formatos de texto. Melhor estudar um pouco. Mas de qualquer forma, obrigado!

Comment: por nada, por favor aceite minha resposta no site Inglês também :)